# Extract text from string when begining and ending words are given in python

Tags: python, string

How can I extract text from a string when begining and ending strings are given?

```
s = "Waiting is a 2015 Indian comedy-drama film directed by Anu Menon, released in India on 27 May 2016. Produced by Priti Gupta of Ishka Films and Manish Mundra of Drishyam Films, the film was co-written by Menon and James Ruzicka"

begining = "Produced"
ending = "Films"
```

Output should be:

> Produced by Priti Gupta of Ishka Films and Manish Mundra of Drishyam Films

Comment: It's a bad idea to name your string `str`, as this shadows the built in `str()` method. I know what you posted is just an example, I thought I'd point this out just in case you didn't know :-)

Comment: Sorry I was in a hurry to ask the question out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution using `str.find` and `str.rfind` functions with an additional check (assuring that both words are found):

```
s = "Waiting is a 2015 Indian comedy-drama film directed by Anu Menon, released in India on 27 May 2016. Produced by Priti Gupta of Ishka Films and Manish Mundra of Drishyam Films, the film was co-written by Menon and James Ruzicka"
begining_str = "Produced"
ending_str = "Films"

b_pos = s.find(begining_str)
e_pos = s.rfind(ending_str)
result = s[b_pos:e_pos + len(ending_str)] if b_pos != -1 and e_pos != -1 else ''

print(result)
```

The output:

```
Produced by Priti Gupta of Ishka Films and Manish Mundra of Drishyam Films
```

Comment: I came across a problem. What if I have repeated words?

Comment: @BharathShetty, then, you should define the rules of the search.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44227820/finding-a-similar-text-present-in-string-in-python). This is the problem what I ran into.

Comment: @BharathShetty, you can initiate a new question with new issue

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [index](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) method of strings in python and use slicing.

For your particular example something like this should work:

```
s[s.index(b):s.index(e)+len(e)]
```

What the code above does is the following: `s.index(b)` finds the first occurrence from the left of the string in `b`. Similar `s.index(e)`. As you want to include the end word as well, we simply add the number of chars in the end string to the last index. `s[x:y]` gives you a "slice" of a string from x to y.