# Finding a similar text present in string in python

Tags: python, string

I have a txt file containing text

> Table of Contents
>
> Preface  1
>
> Chapter 1: Tokenizing Text and WordNet Basics    7
>
> Tokenizing text into sentences    8
>
> Tokenizing sentences into words   10
>
> Tokenizing sentences using regular expressions    12

If the string I have is :

```
input = "Tokenzing sentence using expressions"
```

I thought of using beginning and ending words to extract the sentence but there are lot of repetitions.

So whats the best way to get the output

> Tokenizing sentences using regular expressions

Comment: Are you sure about matching Tokenzing with Tokenizing? or it's just mistake?

Comment: Yes. I want to find the most similar text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are prepared to preprocess your chapter headings, eliminating page numbers and stuff, this:

```
import difflib
contents = ["Tokenizing Text and WordNet Basics",
            "Tokenizing text into sentences",
            "Tokenizing sentences into words",
            "Tokenizing sentences using regular expressions"]
input = "Tokenzing sentence using expressions"
print (difflib.get_close_matches(input, contents, n=1))
```

will give you this output:

```
['Tokenizing sentences using regular expressions']
```